# Overwriting cells of an excel file without affecting the other sheets

Tags: python, xlwt

i'm using python 2.7
I tried like this

```
from xlrd import *
from xlwt import *
file1 = r"abc.xls"
wbfile1 = open_workbook(file1)
file2 = r"xyz.xls"
wbfile2 = Workbook()
SheetName_file2 = wbfile2.add_sheet('sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
SheetName_file2.write(10,10,"Overwrite cell")
wbfile2.save(file2)
```

If i run this, cell(10,10) of sheet1 is changed to `Overwrite cell` and remaining cells get deleted. Is there any way to keep all the cells unaffected?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling add_sheet this will create a NEW BLANK sheet all the time, try commenting it out.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
from xlrd import *
from xlwt import *
file1 = r"abc.xls"
file2 = r"xyz.xls"

wbfile1 = open_workbook(file1)
wbfile1.get_sheet(0).write(10,10,"Overwrite cell")
wbfile1.save(file2)
```